# Lattice sums (solid state physics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, crystals

> The potential in a crystal doesn't only depend on the distance between 2 atoms, but also with the interaction to all $j^{th}$ neighbour-atoms. The Lennard-Jones-Potential then becomes
>
> $U(R_j)=\sum\limits_j 4\epsilon(\frac{\sigma^{12}}{R^{12}}-\frac{\sigma^6}{R^6})=4\epsilon(A_{12}\frac{\sigma^{12}}{R^{12}}-A_6\frac{\sigma^6}{R^6})$
>
> with the lattice sums
>
> $A_n=\sum\limits_j \frac{1}{a_j^n}$, where as $a_j=\frac{R_j}{R}$.
>
> R is the smallest distance between two neighbouring atoms in a crystal. Determine the lower limit of the lattice sums $A_6$ and $A_{12}$ by looking at the interactions to the next 6 neighbouring atoms of a central atom. Determine the $a_j$ for the first 6 neighbour atoms and the number of atoms **N** of the neigbours with the same $a_j$ for an **sc, bcc** and **fcc** lattice. Take a corner atom of a cubic lattice as the central atom.

We started our first solid state physics course this semester and this is one of the problems I can't find an approach to. I've been reading Kittel's book on solid state physics but I couldn't seem to get any idea for this particular problem.

As far as I understand I have to computer the sum for $A_n$ for $j=1,...,6$ and find the lowest value it can get? I assume $R_j$ is the distance to the $j^{th}$-neighbouring atom, correct? In which case $\frac{R_1}{R}=1$ for all three cases (sc, bcc and fcc), right?

But how would I go on about that? I tried drawing a lattice for all three cases and calculate the distance to the j-th neighbouring atom for each case, but couldn't get a proper term/equation for the distance.

Anyone got any ideas?